# Show that the relation by transformation matrice

Tags: special-relativity, linear-algebra

Assume we have the following,
$$
\Lambda^{\alpha}_{\mu} \Lambda^{\beta}_{\nu}\eta_{\alpha \beta} = \eta_{\mu \nu}
$$
How to obtain
$$
\Lambda_{\sigma}^{\alpha}\Lambda_{\beta}^{\sigma} = \delta_{\beta}^{\alpha}
$$
and then show that inverse Lorentz transformation.

Comment: multiply everything with $\eta^{\nu\rho}$

Comment: Yes. I also did this. But I want to obtain $\delta$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$, not $\rho$ and $\mu$

Comment: You can rename indices. For example, $A^\mu=B^\mu$ is the same equation as $A^\alpha=B^\alpha$. Do you understand why?

Comment: I think it is dummy variable. Is it right ?

Comment: That kind of index is called a “free index” because you are free to set $\mu$ or $\alpha$ to 0, 1, 2, or 3. Any such choice gives a valid component equation. Both equations with Greek indices just represent the four component equations $A^0=B^0$, $A^1=B^1$, $A^2=B^2$, and $A^3=B^3$. It doesn’t matter whether you use an index named $\mu$ or one named $\alpha$ to represent these four components.